# Could not cast value of type 'Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>' (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT)

Tags: swift

when I run the app, I get an error (Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) in the line below.

```
var items = [Item]()

func updateCoinData(json : JSON) {

    if let coinData = json[].arrayObject {

        self.items = coinData as! [Item]   //Thread 1: signal SIGABRT
    }else {

        print("cannot connect to the server")
    }

    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You have to set index in json[], because it is an array. You get sigabrt, because there are no data.

Comment: thanks it worked but I didn't understand, I wrote any random word like json["bcd"] and it worked